# is possible to debug android apps downloaded from Play?

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, android-emulator, google-play

My app, when downloaded from Google Play, is showing some errors that I couldn't simulate with eclipse, even debugging directly at the device.

I've posted this issue with more details here: [Facebook Connect works different on emulator/device, but not on Google Play](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11688296/facebook-connect-works-different-on-emulator-device-but-not-on-google-play)

But i want to know if I can debug my app if I downloaded it from Play, i.e., without installing the apk from Eclipse. If not debug, at least could I see the log messages in LogCat?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It's the same as debugging with the eclipse debug apk. You can see log messages, take screenshots. Not sure about breakpoints, but the rest is the same.

Keep in mind that if you use ProGuard or similar tools, the stacktraces will need to be run through their tool again to make sense.

Comment: I wonder if you can attach the source code and use breakpoints (assuming you don't use ProGuard)? Would be interesting...

Comment: I didn't got it... when I click on "debug" on eclipse, with an android device plugged in, it installs a new apk on the device. But i want to debug the apk i've already donwloaded from google play...

Comment: Don't click the debug icon. Just connect the device, switch to the debug tab and open your app from the phone.

Comment: Any info appeared at the debug tab when i do that. Any new line at LogCat and Console either...

Comment: Trying opening the command line, and running adb logcat > log.txt. That'll save the LogCat to the log.txt file